# Parse "dd/mm/yyyy" into Date Kotlin

Tags: date, kotlin, parsing, localdate, date-parsing

I use an GET API request and I receive a string with the format "dd/mm/yyyy". I would like to know how to parse it into Date type in Kotlin.

Here you have my code but I receive error
' java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '04/10/2022' could not be parsed at index 2'

```
 val dateProduct = LocalDate.parse(
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Date"),
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d / M / yyyy")
                )
                val expirationDate = Date
                    .from(dateProduct
                        .atStartOfDay()
                        .atZone(
                            ZoneId
                                .systemDefault()
                        )
                        .toInstant())
```

Comment: you do say `dd/MM/yyyy` but your code is `d / M / yyyy`, any reason for that?

Comment: You resolved my problem thx :)

Comment: np, I'd suggest investing in a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). It helped me quite a few times in cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESOLVED thx @Alex.T:

```
val dateProduct = LocalDate.parse(
                jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Date"),
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
            )
            val expirationDate = Date
                .from(dateProduct
                    .atStartOfDay()
                    .atZone(
                        ZoneId
                            .systemDefault()
                    )
                    .toInstant())
```